# Create div dynamically with options for the selected object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

I have a component that is draggable, and would enable the option to select when you show a little div on one corner, with some options (delete, new). Well, I'm trying to see some components some programming to do that, and unfortunately found nothing practical. There are some library but has a size gigange (versions with 112KB min.)

some of his friends, he would tell me somewhere or I can achieve something similar, or a component that makes it more optimized?

Thanks

*Obs.: I am using jQuery and jQueryUI.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwser:

```
    $("#snaptarget").droppable({
    accept: '#snaptarget > img, #divPrompt > img',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var id   = ui.draggable.attr('id'); 
        var top  = ui.draggable.css('top');
        var src  = ui.draggable.attr('src');
        var left = ui.draggable.css('left');

        ui.draggable.remove();

        $('#snaptarget').prepend('<img id="' + id + '" name="dropped" src="' + src + '" style="position:absolute;" onmouseover="javascript:showDiv(this);" onmouseout="javascript:setTimeout(function(){ removeDiv(' + id + '); },200);"/>');
        $('#' + id).css({ "top" : top, "left" : left });
        $('#' + id).draggable({ snap: true, revert: 'invalid', cursor: 'move', containment: 'document', scroll: false,
                                    drag: function() {
                                        $("div [name='divOptions']").remove();
                                    },
                              });
    }
});

showDiv = function(objCurrent){
    var IdParent = $(objCurrent).closest("div").attr("id");
    if ($.trim(IdParent) == "snaptarget"){
        var Id        = $(objCurrent).attr("id");
        var leftPos   = $(objCurrent).css("left");
        var bottomPos = parseInt($(objCurrent).css("bottom")) - 20 + "px";

        $('#snaptarget').prepend(
                                '<div id="divOpc' + Id + '" name="divOptions" onmouseover="javascript:bolOverride=true;">' +
                                    '<div id="divMenu' + Id + '" name="divMenuInsert" onmouseover="javascript:bolOverride=true;">' +
                                        '<img src="images/BotaoAdicionar.png" width="12" height="12" alt="Adicionar Roda Simples" onclick="addRodaSimples();" onmouseover="javascript:bolOverride=true;" onmouseout="javascript:bolOverride=false;removeDiv('+ Id + ');"/>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                                );

        $('#divOpc' + Id).css({"left" : leftPos, "bottom" : bottomPos, "width" : "10px", "height" : "10px", "border-color" : "#F0F", "position" : "absolute" });
    }
}

removeDiv = function(objCurrent){
    var IdParent = $(objCurrent).closest("div").attr("id");
    if (($.trim(IdParent) == "snaptarget")&&(bolOverride==false)){
        $("#divOpc" + $(objCurrent).attr('id')).remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a draggable window, jquery UI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is the plugin for that. It has a button API that you can use to define your own buttons.

Comment: unfortunately, I need something quieter (interface). A dialog interrupt the workflow of the user on the screen.

Comment: @Ph.E you don't have to turn on modal. A dialog is just a draggable div. If it looks 'loud' to you, then you can easily retheme it to be quieter.